# Unable to run Windows 10 using VMware 15 pro on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: virtualization, windows-10, vmware

I am trying to use Windows 10 on Ubuntu 19.04. 
When I click the Start button, I get the following error:

```
Unable to change virtual machine power state: This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.
(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'
(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.
(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Workstation.
(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.
This host does not support "Intel EPT" hardware assisted MMU virtualization.
Module 'CPUIDEarly' power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

Comment: Did you enable virtualization in your BIOS?

Comment: Virtualization is enabled.

Comment: Did you carefully do steps 1 through 4 listed in the error? Are you sure you did each one properly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment. But this sure sounds like either:

- BIOS settings not correct. (There are typically multiple virtualization-related BIOS settings, not just one.)
- Older hardware?

Without more information it's going to be hard to get much help. Information such as:

- Where are you seeing the error you noted?
- What are your hardware specs (including make, model, ~year, CPU, RAM, etc.)?
- Do you have virtualization enabled in the Windows 10 VM configuration?

Here's some links that might help:

- Linux host: Utility to show if virtualization hardware can be accessed.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cpu-checker
  sudo kvm-ok
  ```
- Window host: [How to find if your computer supports Intel VT-X or AMD-V in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-windows-10)
- [CPU information app for Linux (like CPU-Z)](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/gtk3-version-of-cpu-g-cpu-z-for-linux/)